# no icons or filesystem in partition while installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, partitioning, filesystem, icons

here a picture:
[image]

and a link: https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=4e292ad6a2&view=att&th=13894b3608347cfe&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=1407738951781842944-1&safe=1&zw&sadnir=1&saduie=AG9B_P-90UfqvUx1Y8mLZGbSwSYU&sadet=1342528638595&sads=J5vmqv6WayRs5pHno-5pbw0_ku8

what can cause it or how to fix? happened also after recreating the Disk On Key of Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 64 Bit

also while exiting the icons have appeared suddenly.
and after wxiting, i was in the LiveCD but none of the program i've installed there was there.

may it be a bug? should tell it in launchbag?

Thanks for helping.

edit:
finally, my way to recognize was trying to reduce every partition, and the one which here minimun of size was bigger than the other-it's windows!

Hope this is helping for you (:

Comment: Check the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of your Ubuntu ISO image , and try using Live USB for installation.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS - i would suggest you to post it as answer ,linking to the bug report too. Thanks.

Comment: @tijybba Added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a [usability bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/947107) that is known at launchpad. Please mark it as affecting you as it clearly affects you. There are currently no plans to fix it, but if you mark it as affecting you, it might persuade a developer.

Comment: done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/947107/comments/8 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just creating another Live CD. If you are concerned you might have the same issue with your currently downloaded disk image, re-download Ubuntu 12.04 then create another Live CD.